# Synchronization of shared memory (int) with java threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, java-memory-model

In our app (written in Java for Android), we have a `Thread` derived class that contains an int field:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    public int myValue = 0;

    public void doWork() {

        while (true) {
            System.out.println(myValue);
        }
    }
}

// On some other thread
myThread.myValue = 42;
```

The `MyThread` class only **reads** from the int field, while i'd like another thread to **write** to it (as in the example above).

As i know, primitive types such as int in Java are read/written atomically.

Should i protect the access to this int field (using the `synchronized` keyword) ?

I've read [here](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.co.il/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html) that according to the Java memory model, updates to memory shared by a few threads may not even be seen if not explicitly communicated

> Quote: Without explicit communication, you can't guarantee which writes get
>   seen by other threads

Should i protect the access to this field or can another thread update it (atomically) without any needed modification?

Comment: In your simple example, you understanding is correct. The problem comes when a thread wants to make a decision based on that value. eg. `if (value == 42)`. Then it enters the body of that `if`, but `value` has been changed to something else. As long as you're aware of this possibility... I say this because these simple examples tend to miss a lot of the complexities of multithreading.

Comment: This contradicts other answers provided here (e.g: should use the volatile keyword)

Comment: Jonathon's comment is correct, and doesn't contradict MY answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include that requirement. I was commenting on both at once and got confused.

Answer (score 3):

What you should do is declare it as `volatile`.  Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html.

Comment: FYI, sames goes for C/C++ (where this keyword comes from)

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the need for it? will the code not perform as it should now?

Comment: You should look up what the `volatile` keyword does. Basically it tells the compiler to not generate any code that "remembers" that value, and instead to always go fetch it from memory.

Comment: The code MIGHTN'T work as you've written it.  The JVM might assume that the variable won't change within the loop, and cache it.  By declaring it as `volatile`, you tell the JVM "don't cache this".  Or your code MIGHT work fine, but you shouldn't risk it.

Comment: @user2511414 That's true, but the OP has specifically said that the reading happens on one thread and the writing on another.

Comment: If the field is not volatile, the value of the field can be inlined because your thread doesn't change the value. This means it might not see you change it in another thread.

Comment: @PeterLawrey how can the compiler inline that value? let's say threading is not involved in the example. I have that loop printing the field, and another method that is writing to that field. How can the compiler inline that access? it would generate the wrong code!

Comment: @lysergic-acid You're exactly right, and that's why you must declare this variable as volatile.

Comment: @lysergic-acid But you don't have another method for that thread, nor do you call a thread safe construct. Just adding an empty `synchronized() { }` block will mean the JIT doesn't do this.http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/demonstrating-when-volatile-is-required.html

Comment: That's a nice article, @PeterLawrey.  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

how are you going to update the int variable? if it's direct-modify, so setting the variable as volatile is useful.
`public volatile int myValue = 0;`

but the update is `read-modify` so you need synchronize threads with each other.
and [[this link]](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#vol0) would be useful for understanding volatile

Answer (score 1):

primitive types such as int in Java are read/written atomically.

A thread always sees the value of a variable that was written by some thread; not some random value pulled out of thin air.  Unless declared as `volatile`, 64-bit numeric variables (long and double) do not have out-of-thin-air safety, because the JVM is permitted to treat 64-bit value as two 32-bit fetch operations. So even though you use primitive type you should use `Volatile`.

One more thing in mutithreading there are two things: **1. atomicity 2. visibility**

Volatile guarantee the visibility part not the atomicity part. so if you are incrementing a variable like `K++` than you should `synchronize` as well else you are not guaranteeing the `atomicity` part.

Comment: Does `volatile` make a 64-bit write atomic, though (on a 32-bit system)? I'm not intimately familiar, but I would imagine that if one thread wrote `0xDEADDEADBEEFBEEF` to a previously zero 64-bit value, that the reader thread might see only `0x00000000BEEFBEEF`.